# How and why is the super class of singleton_class of BasicObject is Class class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, singleton

By definition, a singleton class of an object also inherits the singleton class of the superclass of the object. The `BasicObject` in ruby doesn't have any superclass as it is the most basic level class

```
>> BasicObject.superclass
=> nil
```

But when the same method called on its singleton class, it results:

```
>> BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass
=> Class
```

and also why no other object in ruby have the `Class` class as its superclass?

How the logic behind the superclass of singleton_class of BasicObject is implemented in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the superclass of the singleton class of an object is the class of the object. I.e. for any object `foo` with a singleton class, the following holds:

```ruby
foo.singleton_class.superclass == foo.class
```

However, for classes, this would be somewhat boring: the class of every class is `Class`, so the superclass of every class's singleton class would always be `Class`.

That is not particularly useful, since it would break some reasonable assumptions. For example, if I have something like this:

```ruby
class Super
  def self.super_singleton_method; end
end

class Sub < Super; end
```

I would expect to be able to call `Sub.super_singleton_method`. However, in order to do this, `Super.singleton_class` needs to be somewhere in the method lookup chain of `Sub.singleton_class`.

So, for classes, the rule is somewhat different: the superclass of the singleton class of a class is the singleton class of the superclass of the class. I.e. for any class `Foo`, the following holds:

```ruby
Foo.singleton_class.superclass == Foo.superclass.singleton_class
```

If you want, you can check whether this is true for every class in your system:

```ruby
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select do |klass|
  klass.singleton_class.superclass != klass.superclass.singleton_class
end
#=> [BasicObject]
```

So, as you can see, this property *does* hold for *all classes except `BasicObject`*.

The simple answer for why `BasicObject` is different is that `BasicObject` has no superclass, and thus we cannot apply the rule. So, we fall back on the more general rule for all objects that

```ruby
foo.singleton_class.superclass == foo.class
```

And `BasicObject`'s class is `Class`, therefore,

```ruby
BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass == BasicObject.class
BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass == Class
```

> and also why no other object in ruby have the `Class` class as its superclass?

The only reason to inherit from `Class` would be to override the behavior of how inheritance or method lookup works in Ruby. But Ruby does not allow to override this. How inheritance and method lookup works is part of the language specification and cannot be changed. Therefore, inheriting from `Class` is illegal:

```ruby
class MyClass < Class; end
# can't make subclass of Class (TypeError)
```

Thus there cannot be any object which has `Class` as its superclass, *except* singleton classes of classes. (Ruby can of course break its own rules since it is the one that makes the rules.)

> How the logic behind the superclass of singleton_class of BasicObject is implemented in Ruby?

It isn't. You cannot explain how this works in Ruby, since it is part of the definition of Ruby itself.

It is similar to how `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, but `Module` is a class, i.e. an instance of `Class`. You cannot explain this from within Ruby using the rules of Ruby, but the Ruby implementation can, of course, set things up so that this works, since the Ruby implementation itself does not have to abide by the rules of Ruby: it is the one enforcing the rules, so it can just choose not to enforce them for itself.

Comment: Thank you for adding this: "It is similar to how `Class` is a subclass of `Module`, but `Module` is a class, i.e. an instance of `Class`" because it is one of the beautiful enigmas of the Ruby implementation.

Answer (score 5):

> By definition, a singleton class of an object also inherits the singleton class of the superclass of the object.

Instead of taking this for granted, let's figure out why it was implemented this way.

In Ruby, there are instance methods and class methods. The class methods however are in fact instance methods of the singleton class:

```
class MyClass
  def foo
  end

  def self.bar
  end
end

MyClass.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:foo]

MyClass.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:bar]
```

As a diagram:

```
MyClass  --->  #<Class:MyClass>
foo            bar
```

Now, if you create a subclass `MySubClass`, it inherits both, the instance methods and the class methods from its superclass `MyClass`:

```
class MySubClass < MyClass
end

MySubClass.instance_methods
#=> [:foo, ...]

MySubClass.singleton_class.instance_methods
#=> [:bar, ...]
```

To get this working, the inheritance has to be established for both, the classes and the singleton classes:

```
MyClass     --->  #<Class:MyClass>
foo               bar
    ^                    ^
    |                    |
MySubClass  --->  #<Class:MySubClass>
```

Ruby optimized this internally – the singleton classes are only created when needed. But conceptually, this is what happens.

Apart from that, `MyClass` and `MySubClass` already come with some built-in class methods, most notably `.new` which is used to create instances, but also `.superclass`.

You might know that the default implementation of `.new` calls `.allocate` under the hood. So somewhere there must be a sort of "root class" which contains these methods. And since they are class methods, it must sit on top of the singleton class side:

```
                  <singleton root class>
                  new
                  allocate
                  superclass
                         ^
                         |
                        ...
                         |
MyClass     --->  #<Class:MyClass>
foo               bar
    ^                    ^
    |                    |
MySubClass  --->  #<Class:MySubClass>
```

And this mysterious top level singleton root class that provides the fundamental class methods for all other classes is ... [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html)!

```
Class.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:allocate, :superclass, :subclasses, :new]
```

Comment: "Ruby optimized this internally – the singleton classes are only created when needed" – I think most Ruby implementations (specifically YARV) optimize the optimization for classes and always create the singleton class. It makes sense to lazily create singleton classes for objects in general, since most objects don't use singleton classes. However, most classes do use singleton classes, so the machinery for lazy creation is just unnecessary overhead. Thus, as an optimization of the optimization, lazy creation does not happen for singleton classes of classes.

Comment: But all of that are just private internal implementation details of specific versions of specific implementations of Ruby, not part of the language semantics. The language semantics are simple: whenever you look for a singleton class, it is there, and you have no way of knowing whether it was lazily created or it was always there. Personally, when I explain singleton classes, I prefer to not mention this optimization at all.

Comment: @JörgWMittag there are secret ways to examine existing classes: `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c.to_s =~ /MyClass/ }`. In YARV, the singleton class appears after creating a class method (`def MyClass.bar ; end`) or when calling `MyClass.singleton_class` explicitly.

Comment: Besides, since each singleton class is a class, each can have its own singleton class, e.g. `MyClass.singleton_class.singleton_class`. I think lazy creation (at some point) is quite essential to get this working.